# Is it possible to edit, compile and run Java code in Xcode?

Tags: java, xcode, java-8, xcode8

I am using Java for my CS class at school, and I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE. Along with this, I am using C++ for my personal projects/college course. Is there any way to edit, compile, and run Java in Xcode so I don't have to switch IDEs?

My current Xcode version is Xcode 8.0 (8A218a). I would like to run using Java 1.8.*.

Comment: [For more on using Xcode for Java development, see the Xcode Help menu.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/02-JavaDevTools/JavaDevTools.html).

Comment: Yea, it is possible.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3651347  At least, in general.

Answer (score 4):

When I was in school, I attempted to do the same exact thing and I found that it took too much time compiling my Java code in Xcode, switching to my terminal to execute the executable, etc. In short, if you enjoy using Xcode, feel free to use it as a text editor but you won't get much use out of it beyond that using Java.

Not to mention, if you decide to pursue a career as a Java Developer, you're far better off mastering an IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse; most companies if not all use them. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will stick to IntelliJ. It's pretty good of an IDE.

Comment: ...and I find gradle infuriating enough!